# phantomjs with webdriver: Can't handle popup/alert

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

I am trying to handle  popup using phantomjs as a driver and I want to copy the text of alert/popup in variable.
I write the code:
But I am getting exception:Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NullPointerException`
Anyone knows how to handle popup/alert using phantomjs with webdriver.
I write the code:

```
 js.executeScript("window.alert = function(msg){JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        document.lastAlert=msg;};");
        Object text = js.executeScript("return document.lastAlert");
        System.out.println(text.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium has methods to interact with javascript alerts. You can interact with a javascript alert as follows:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

From here on you can get the alert text with:

```
String alertText = alert.getText();
```

You do not need any javascript to do this. Just plain Java code does all that for you.